# Xamarin Forms: ScrollView returns to begging on TranslateTo

Tags: xamarin, scrollview, xamarin.forms

Well when I call TranslateTo an scrollview on XamarinForms it's both ScrollX and ScrollY becomes 0, which is very annoying for me because our layout design needs that kind of animation. Anyone has any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Maybe you could wrap `ScrollView` inside `ContentView` and do the `TranslateTo` on `ContentView`? Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Luberda suggested, if you put your scrollview inside contentview and transate the contentview, scroll view's scroll indexes does not return to 0.