# Xamarin Forms: Change the size of scrollview on translateto

Tags: xamarin, scrollview, xamarin.forms

What I am trying to do is:

I have a scrollview inside my view and it's height is like 2/9 of the parent height. Then user can translate this scrollview to make it bigger. However scrollview's size does not change obviously. So even though it is bigger scrollview's size remains the same, killing the point. I could make it bigger initially. However it won't scroll since the size is big enough not to scroll.

I don't know if was able to explain it right. Hope i did.

Regards.

**Edit
-------------**

Some code to explain my point further

This is the scrollview

```
public class TranslatableScrollView : ScrollView
{
        public Action TranslateUp { get; set; }
        public Action TranslateDown { get; set; }
        bool SwipedUp;
    public TranslatableScrollView()
    {
        SwipedUp = false;
        Scrolled += async delegate {
            if (!SwipedUp && ScrollY > 0) {
                TranslateUp.Invoke ();
                SwipedUp = true;
            } else if (SwipedUp && ScrollY <= 0) {

                TranslateDown.Invoke ();
                SwipedUp = false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And this is the code in the page

```
sv_footer = new TranslatableScrollView {
                    Content = new StackLayout {
                        VerticalOptions =         LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                        Children = {
                            l_details,
                            l_place
                        },
                    }
                };
sv_footer.TranslateUp += new Action (async delegate {

                Parent.ForceLayout();
                await cv_scrollContainer.TranslateTo(0, -transX, aSpeed, easing);
            });

sv_footer.TranslateDown += new Action (async delegate {
                await cv_scrollContainer.TranslateTo(0, 0, aSpeed, easing);
            });

cv_scrollContainer = new ContentView {
                Content = sv_footer,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
            };
```

I put the scrollview inside a contentview otherwise Its scroll indexes becomes 0 when they are translated. Ref: [Xamarin Forms: ScrollView returns to begging on TranslateTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216212/xamarin-forms-scrollview-returns-to-begging-on-translateto)

Comment: Could you include a couple images to help describe the situation?  I think it might help people better understand the question.  How does the user "translate" the scroll view?  Does this mean that the user is scrolling the contents of the scrollview in the direction of the scrollview?  If so, are you wanting the scrollview to increase in size when the user begins scrolling its content?

Comment: Yeah thats actually what I want exactly.

Comment: Have you tried using the Scrolled event to listen for scrolls?  I don't really understand the problem you're experiencing.  Can you post some of the code that you're using?

Comment: I just did, the problem is that, widthrequest property does not do the trick, I forced the parent layout which is relative layout and that did not do the trick either.

Comment: If the View is inside of a RelativeLayout, then WidthRequest property has no affect.  The RelativeLayout uses constraints to layout its children, and will ignore the request properties.  You will have to change the constraints or use a different layout.

Comment: Is there a way to change the constraints later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, translateTo only changes the position of the element. I could use scaleTo after the translation. However it changes the both dimensions. Someone from Xamarin Forums suggested me to use LayoutTo which I did not know existed. With layoutTo you can change both the size and location. Giving an instance of Rectangle type.